# Represent String pattern in lex file

Tags: java, lex

How do you represent a string in lex file?

I've tried the following:

```
{NUM}* {ID}* { return new Symbol(sym.STR);}
```

But received an error as:

```
Description: + ? or * must follow an expression or subexpression.
```

Also tried:

```
{ {NUM}* | {ID}* }+ { return new Symbol(sym.STR);}
```

and the error is: Description: `Macro does not exist`.
But the macro has already been defined as:

```
enter code here
%%
%cup
%line
NUM = [0-9]
ID = [a-zA-Z]
WhiteSpace = [ \t\r\n\f]
%%
```

Comment: The definitions section doesn't use `=`.  Try `NUM [0-9]`.

Comment: That could not be the error because the rule 
{NUM}+ { return new Symbol(sym.NUMBER, new Integer(yytext())); } has no error when compiled or executed.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373742/how-to-recognize-string-in-lex-file