# How to recognize string in Lex file

Tags: lex

Hi what would be appropriate to recognize string in a lex.

I have already tried

```
enter code here

import java_cup.runtime.*;

%%
%cup
%line
NUM = [0-9]
ID = [a-zA-Z]
Pun= [:=;#@$^~]
WhiteSpace = [ \t\r\n\f]
SDQuo = [\"]
%%


({SDQuo}+) ({ID}|{NUM})* ({SDQuo}+) { return new Symbol(sym.STR, new String(yytext()));}
```

but the macro fail to be recognized.
The error message that I kept getting is:
Processing first section -- user code.
Processing second section -- JLex declarations.
Processing third section -- lexical rules.
Creating NFA machine representation.
Error: Parse error at line 39.
Description: Missing brace at start of lexical action.
Parse error.

Answer (score 1):

Loose the `=` signs in the definitions of `NUM` etc. and don't place them between `%%`. Instead place the last rule between `%%`.